# ng-show does not update in a ng-repeat loop

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some hierarchical data (some kind of a tree view) that represents an organization chart. I want to show this in a table. I did the following:

```
<tr ng-repeat="dat in vm.refined" ng-show="dat.show || dat.parent==null">
   <td ng-click="vm.toggleShow(dat)" style="cursor: pointer">
       <span ng-class="(dat.show===true || dat.parent===null) ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'" ></span>
      {{dat.value.rbsName}}
    </td>
    <td>{{dat.parent}}</td>  <!-- ignore these two tds -->
    <td>{{dat.members}}</td> <!-- ignore these two tds --> 
</tr>
```

vm.refined is an array of objects, defined in the controller which has the name of the unit, its parent (if any, else null) and a show flag to simulate the collapse/expand.

toggleShow() responsibility is to... toggle the show flag in the selected (which will be shown anyway due to being parent) and to its children. So I do something like:

```
vm.toggleShow=function(dat) {
        dat.show=!dat.show;
        for(var i=0; i< vm.refined.length; i++) {
          if(vm.refined[i].parent==dat.parent)
            vm.refined[i].show=!vm.refined[i].show;
        }        
      };
```

Thing is that when I click the td, toggleShow is called but I will not see the rows I am supposed to see. It seems like a scope issue and ng-repeat but I cannot find a solution around. Can you help? Oh and something else, do you feel it would be better if I write this part as a directive?

Comment: ng-show can be minimized to `ng-show="dat.show || dat.parent"`

Comment: @pankajparkar Thanks. Actually I had something like ng-show="vm.showRow(dat)", a function like return (dat.show===true || dat.parent===null); but nothing works. I come from C/c++ and javascript vagueness on nulls, undefined etc freaks me out from time to time!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of your problem ? From what I read it looks like it should change the `show` attributes of all of the other children that dat.parent has, but keep the dat pressed the same, since you switch it on the entry to toggleShow and switch it back in the for loop.

Comment: @TheGoblin you could handle that method on UI itself `ng-click="dat.show=!dat.show;"`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are toggling function is doing nothing. At the start of the function it is toggling flag & then you are looping through the array & when it found you are toggling that flag. By doing that your value is true the it became true only, Nothing will be change in value.

I think you should toggle that flag on html itself

**Markup**

```
<tr ng-repeat="dat in vm.refined" ng-show="dat.show || dat.parent">
   <td ng-click="dat.show=!dat.show" style="cursor: pointer">
       <span ng-class="(dat.show || dat.parent) ? 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right' : 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down'" ></span>
      {{dat.value.rbsName}}
    </td>
    <td>{{dat.parent}}</td>  <!-- ignore these two tds -->
    <td>{{dat.members}}</td> <!-- ignore these two tds --> 
</tr>
```

Comment: I use the toggling function because I have to toggle the show flag to all elements that has as parent the selected item. For instance, if we have item A that has {parent: null} I will show it anyway since  it is ORed with dat.parent==true. When I select the item, all items like b={parent:A.description, show=false} and c={parent:A.description, show:false} will turn to true.

Comment: the you don't need `dat.show=!dat.show;` in your function

Comment: @TheGoblin did you try that?